# Simplify code with named self invoking function

Tags: javascript

I have this script:

```
function fixHeight () {
  $(".sidebar-mainbox-container").height($(window).height());
})

fixHeight();

$(window).on("resize", function() {
  fixHeight();
})
```

I'm looking for a way to simplify it using a self invoking function and then call it in the resize event.
I've tried this one:

```
var fixHeight = (function () {
  $(".sidebar-mainbox-container").height($(window).height());
})();
$(window).on("resize", function() {
  fixHeight();
})
```

But in this way the value of the self-invoked function is assigned to `fixHeight`, and this can't work.
If I remove the self-invoking part...

```
var fixHeight = (function () {
  $(".sidebar-mainbox-container").height($(window).height());
});
$(window).on("resize", function() {
  fixHeight();
})
```

Then the function works only when I call it on resize, and this is not good.

How can I simplify this code to avoid 3 elements for such a simple task?

Comment: FYI, `$(window).on("resize", function() { fixHeight();});` can be written more concisely as `$(window).on("resize", fixHeight);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's wrong with

```
$(window).on("resize", function() {
  $(".sidebar-mainbox-container").height( $(this).height() );
});
```

?

To avoid an extra function call just trigger the event immediately after registering it.

```
$(window).on("resize", /* ... */).trigger("resize");
```

Comment: The function will only be called on resize events. The question is asking how to call it immediately **and** on resize events.

Comment: Thank you the trigger function works, may you update your answer so I can set it as correct?

Comment: Ah maybe would be better use a namespaced event to avoid conflicts with other event listeners?   `$(window).on("resize.fixheight", /* ... */).trigger("resize.fixheight");`

Comment: Possibly, but not very likely in this case. It's improbable that any event handler listening for a "resize" type of event breaks something just because that event actually happens.

Comment: Yes but if someone else read this question and has a different event a name spaced event will save lot of time :)